# Principal ideal of a non-associative magma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, magma, nonassociative-algebras

The definitions of a left, right, and two-sided ideal of an algebra do not involve associativity
(R.D. Schafer *"An Introduction To Nonassociative Algebras"*).

The same we can say about the definitions of a left and right principal ideal of a semigroup.
However, the definition of a two-sided principal ideal of a semigroup involves the product $SaS$
which assumes associativity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations).

Is it possible to extend the definition of a two-sided principal ideal to a non-associative magma?
Can we simply replace $SaS$ with $(Sa)S \cup S(aS)$ in the definition for a semigroup?

Are there definitions of principal ideals for non-associative rings, algebras, etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can help you but I can share some ideas. If you define the principal ideal generated by "a" on a non-associative magma $S$ by $(Sa)S\cup S(aS)\cup aS\cup Sa\cup\{a\}$ you may find some problems e.g. take $S=\{0,a,b\}$ with $xy=0, \forall x,y\in S$. What is the ideal generated by "a"? It should be $I=\{a\}$ but $SI\not\subset I$. Maybe there is some other way to define such concept but I am not aware of any.

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien It looks like we cannot say that an element of a magma generates an ideal. An element of a magma generates a "generated subset". The "generated subset" may or may not be a principal ideal. A "generated subset" of an element is always a principal ideal in an associative magma.

Comment: Why a "generated subset" of an element is always a principal ideal in an associative magma? For instance, the magma I gave you is associative since $(xy)z=0z=x0=x(yz)$.

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien By the definition for a semigroup the principal ideal of $a$ in your case (in a zero semigroup) is $\{0, a\}$, isn't it?

Comment: I overlooked that and my example is wrong as it shoud say $I=\{0,a\}$. I must think a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long to post as comment and I appreciate if you correct any mistake. I'm assuming $I_A=Sa\cup aS \cup S(aS)\cup (Sa)S\cup\{a\}$.

Consider the magma $(S,.)$ with $S=\{i,a,b,c\}$ and with product given by the table:

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}
 & i & a & b & c\\ \hline
i & a & c & i & a\\ \hline
a & a & a & a & a\\ \hline
b & a & a & a & a\\ \hline
c & a & a & a & b 
\end{array}
$

Then $aS=\{a\},Sa=\{a,c\},(Sa)S=\{a,b\},S(aS)=\{a,c\}$ so $I_a=\{a,b,c\}$ but $i=(ib)\in S.I_a$ and $i\notin I_a$.

If $(S,.)$ is associative one always have $S((Sa)S)\subset (Sa)S=S(aS)\subset I_a$ and this construction fails. It's true that $S.I_a\subset I_a$ for non-associative magmas that satisfy $S=aS$ for every $a\in S$ but it may be too much to ask. However if every element $a\in S$ satisfies $S\setminus\{a\}=aS\cup Sa$ then $I_a$ satisfies $S.I_a\subset I_a$ even if the magma is not associative. To see this, note that an element $x\in S.I_a$ satisfying $x\notin I_a$ must be of the form $i((s_1a)s_2)$ or $i(s_1(as_2))$ for some $i,s_1,s_2\in S$, in both cases we have an element of S as the operation is closed, this implies $i((s_1a)s_2),i(s_1(as_2))\in aS\cup Sa \cup \{a\}\subset I_a$.